# How to extend an Activity in Kotlin like extension of UIViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin

First of all I don't want these [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

Here is my example in swift,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    etc...
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    etc...
}
```

So with this way I keep my class clean and have everything organised in "extension blocks"

Here is what I have in Kotlin and my question is if I can do something similar with my swift code

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity(), MyManagerListener2, MyManagerListener {
    override fun onSuccessMyManagerListener() {}

    override fun onSuccessMyManagerListener2() {}
}
```

Two Listeners so I want two "extensions" like

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {} 

extension MyActivity: MyManagerListener2 {
    override fun onSuccessMyManagerListener2() {}
}

extension MyActivity: MyManagerListener {
    override fun onSuccessMyManagerListener() {}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not entirely what your looking for, but you can organise your code in regions by starting the part you want to group together with `//region <name of region>` and ending it with `//endregion`. This makes you able to collapse and expand parts of your code as you wish. for example it would look like this

[image]

When you collapse it by pressing the little button in front of it you will get this:

[image]

I'm not familiar with Swift extension so I don't know if this is really what you're looking for or if they have other benefits, but it can maybe make your code look cleaner.

Comment: I upvoted the answer as it is very interesting but not what I want, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin does not allow you to override methods with an extension. Neither does Swift. In Swift, you are declaring adherence to the protocol in the extension, not the class definition, so you are not actually overriding a function. The shortcoming in Kotlin is that you can't use an extension to make a class adhere to an interface, so you can't do this either way.

In my opinion, what you're doing there in Swift is an abuse of a feature that's intended for something else. It's intended for allowing you to make a class more versatile by using its already public features. But if you're manipulating its internal members with the extension, then you have to make the members public. So you are breaking encapsulation in two different ways for no real benefit.